# UTC Time server difference

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a client and server side application. The client is on UK server and the server is on US one.

There is an validation on the server which check when the message was sent from client and compare it to see the time difference.

This is how I get the time span on client app (UK):

```
DateTime epochStart = new DateTime(1970, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
TimeSpan timeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow - epochStart;
// Convert to string before send it to server 
string requestTimeStamp = Convert.ToUInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString()
```

On the server (US) end I have:

```
DateTime epochStart = new DateTime(1970, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
TimeSpan currentTs = DateTime.UtcNow - epochStart;

var serverTotalSeconds = Convert.ToUInt64(currentTs.TotalSeconds);
var requestTotalSeconds = Convert.ToUInt64(requestTimeStamp);

if ((serverTotalSeconds - requestTotalSeconds) > requestMaxAgeInSeconds)
{
     //....
}
```

Everything works fine when the server and client are on UK server but the problems appears when there are on different one.

My questions are:

1. Is UTC time exact same on both servers no matter the time zone/time difference?
2. Is the time taken from the PC system time? (so if the time is set to wrong one in the system the `DateTime.UtcNow` give me wrong time?)

Comment: "but the problems appears ..." - could you actually describe to us what the problems are?

Comment: correct on both counts. in particular, if the server time is even a few seconds out, your comparisons won't be wholly accurate. however, if all messages are coming into the US server, then this inaccuracy will be consistant, so you should be a ble to form a strategy to deal with it

Comment: Take a look at this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773013%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: When machine time is set wrong, all your assumptions will start to break. UTC time will report the wrong value based on machine time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is UTC time exact same on both servers no matter the time zone/time difference?

*In theory*, it should be. However, depending on the NTP server that both client and server talk to they could potentially be different. Hopefully if they are different, it's a *very* small difference.

> Is the time taken from the PC system time? (so if the time is set to wrong one in the system the DateTime.UtcNow give me wrong time?)

Yes, [MSDN's DateTime.UtcNow documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow(v=vs.110).aspx) says the following:

> Gets a DateTime object that is set to the current date and time on this computer, expressed as the Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

Comment: so just to clarify if the client machine time is 2PM and time zone is UCT(London, Dublin, etc) and the server time is 6AM (8 hs behind) and the time zone is U.S.A. – California – San Francisco the DateTime.UtcNow should show exact same time?

Comment: `DateTime.UtcNow` *should* show the exact time. There **can** be  discrepancies, but they **should** be very small. My best guess would be at most milliseconds of difference. If you're needing precision down to ticks across a network, then you need to rethink your strategy.